# How to use Python subprocess to write multiple inputs into custom exe program

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, input, subprocess

I am trying to open a executable that opens a HEC .dss database file. However, I can only seem to get it to read one argument after opening the exe and then it doesn't read anything else. Is there any way to force it to keep inserting commands.

This exe has some unique features to it, which include that the first command asks what DSS file you are going to read. Then you can input a command to create the output txt file that it will write to for the rest of the commands. What I've been able to do so far is to start the program and run one command into the exe (the **mydss** variable). However, after that first command is read, none of the other commands are used in the command prompt. I feel like I'm missing something here. Here is the code:

```
##Testing on how to run and use the DSSUTL program
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

DSSUTL = "C:\Users\sduncan\Documents\HEC-DSS\HEC-DSSVue-2_0_1\FromSivaSel\DSSUTL.exe"
mydss = "C:\Users\sduncan\Documents\HEC-DSS\HEC-DSSVue-2_0_1\FromSivaSel\\forecast.dss"
firstLine = "WR.T TO=PythonTextOutput.txt"
commandLine = "WR.T B=SHAVER RESERVOIR-POOL C=FLOW-IN E=1HOUR F=10203040"
myList = [firstLine, commandLine]
ps = subprocess.Popen([DSSUTL, mydss, myList[1], myList[0]], shell=True)
```

I've also tried including **stdin=subprocess.PIPE**, but that only leads to the exe opening and it is blank (when I open it with the code above I can read it and see that the mydss variable was read correctly). When I used **stdout** or **sterr**, the program only opens and closes.

I've also tried using the code when the **stdin=PIPE** was turned on with:

```
ps.stdin.write(myList[1])
ps.stdin.write(myList[0])
ps.communicate()[0]
```

However, it did not read anything in the program. This program runs like a command prompt, however, it's not the typical cmd as it was made to read the DSS filetype and produce a text file with the list from searches like in the **commandLine** variable

It would be nice to know what I could do to fix the code so that I could input the extra commands. Any help to know how to event check if the commands were being sent or processed by this exe. Eventually, I will be adding many more commands to the exe file to print to the text file, so if there is any way to get python to write to the exe that would help.

Comment: Its an interactive program and you want to drive that interaction with python? This would be possible on Linux systems using the `pexpect` module much much harder on windows. There is [some limited support](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows) but I don't know if it will work for you.

Comment: Its common for interactive programs to also have a scripting interface. If your program does that then you may be able to write a command to stdin to get what you want.

Comment: @tdelaney, it's often possible using the console API in a C extension or via ctypes. If the parent process is attached to the same console as the child, then it can write to the console's input buffer and read from the console's active screen buffer.

Comment: @eryksun - yes... but you have to track the buffer and poll it for changes and that's a heavy lift! Even then, the windows libc thinks its a pipe and if the progam is libc based its behavior could be problematic.

Comment: @tdelaney, yes to your first response, though you can create a new screen buffer with 9999 lines, all initialized with NULs to make it easy to read lines from the screen (in many cases). Most console programs are line oriented rather than a curses style program that actively paints the screen, so waiting on the console handle and tracking the cursor position should suffice. It gets to be a heavy lift when the console has to scroll the buffer. The 2nd comment doesn't make sense to me. The CRT won't treat a console handle like a pipe.

Comment: @eryksun - programs that use libc to write to stdout don't know about the console buffer. They may act differently if not attached to a tty. Windows libraries follow tty rules just like unix systems, its just that its very difficult to set that tty bit to create a unix style pty. When running the program from cmd.exe, the program sees a tty on stdin but that tty is created by cmd.exe. When running from another program it sees a pipe.

Comment: @tdelaney, the console is conhost.exe. cmd.exe is just a client, the same as python.exe. Every process has a slot for a console handle (either a kernel handle for `\Device\ConDrv` in Windows 8+ or an ALPC handle in older versions) for a single console connection, plus 3 standard handles, which can be anything. Prior to Windows 8, IPC between the client and host had to use the ALPC handle, since console buffer handles were only meaningful to the console host process. In 8+ a lot of IPC (for the console API) uses the buffer handles directly via system calls such as `NtDeviceIoControlFile`.

Comment: @tdelaney, I stated from the outset that both the parent and child have to be attached to the same console, so the child process is attached to a console, and its `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError` handles are to be left as console buffers (but maybe use a new screen buffer for the output handles, since that can make life easier), not disk files or pipes. The CRT will not use full buffering on console handles.

Answer (score 0):

@tdelaney, @eryksun Thank you for commenting, your comments about the pipes and delay really helped. I was able to fix the problem by using this code:

```
##Testing on how to run and use the DSSUTL program
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
import time

DSSUTL = "C:\Users\sduncan\Documents\HEC-DSS\HEC-DSSVue-2_0_1\FromSivaSel\DSSUTL.exe"
mydss = "C:\Users\sduncan\Documents\HEC-DSS\HEC-DSSVue-2_0_1\FromSivaSel\\forecast.dss"
location = "WR.T TO=PythonTextOutput.txt" + " WR.T B=SHAVER RESERVOIR-POOL C=FLOW-IN E=1HOUR F=10203040" + "\n"
filecontent1 = "WR.T B=FLORENCE RESERVOIR-POOL C=FLOW-IN E=1HOUR F=10203040" + "\n"
filecontent2 = "WR.T B=HUNTINGTON LAKE-POOL C=FLOW-IN E=1HOUR F=10203040" + "\n"
filecontentList = [filecontent1, filecontent2]
myList = [DSSUTL, mydss] # commandLine, location
ps = subprocess.Popen(myList , shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
time.sleep(1)
# input into stdin
ps.stdin.write(location)
time.sleep(1)
ps.stdin.write(filecontent1)
time.sleep(1)
ps.stdin.write(filecontent2)
time.sleep(1)
print ps.communicate()[0]
# End Script
```

By using the pipes to talk to the program and putting a time delay seemed to fix the problem and allowed me to talk to the console. Even though the console display is blank, by printing the communicate() command, it outputs what the console did and produce the text file with the wanted series.

Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: It looks like the relevant change here is adding a trailing `'\n'` to each line of input, which you could instead put at the end of each string literal, e.g. use `'string\n'` instead of `'string' + '\n'`. The `sleep()` calls shouldn't be required; you're just writing to a pipe. You should be able to join the 3 strings and write it as the `input` argument to `communicate`.  FYI, you *are not* talking to a console; each of the 3 standard handles is a pipe. Actually, you've made `stdout` and `stderr` the same pipe, but I don't recommend that in most cases.