# How to simulate the commands of windows executable using python script?

Tags: python

I have executable control_client.exe at `\Users\rjras\Desktop\mqtt\winutils_20210211_153118`

Please find below the commands that I use to run the executable:

```
C:\Users\rjras\Desktop\mqtt\winutils_20210211_153118>control_client -mac abcdefgh -user xxx -pass xxx -web_mqtt
Control Client for abc company. Version 1.05.
addr: wss://example.net:443/ws_mqtt
Attempt MQTT connect
Successfully connected via MQTT
subscribe event topic abcdefgh/command/confirm
> position 1 detect on
Sending topic abcdefgh/command/request JSON {"request":"abcdefgh/control/position/1/detect/on","id":0}
> Msg topic: abcdefgh/command/confirm, Payload: {"status":"OK","id":0}
```

There are two commands here.

1. `control_client -mac abcdefgh -user xxx -pass xxx -web_mqtt` - Connects to remote server using this credentials and opens a terminal. I need to run the second command here.
2. `position 1 detect on` - It detects that the event at position 1 occurred.

I have written an equivent simple python script below:

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.Popen("control_client -mac abcdefgh -user xxx -pass xxx -web_mqtt",
                       shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\rjras\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\rjras\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53473 --file C:/Users/rjras/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main-control_client.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 211.7142.13)
subscribe event topic abcdefgh/command/confirm
Msg topic: abcdefgh/command/confirm, Payload: {"status":"OK","id":0}
```

I am not sure how do I send the second command in the script.

Comment: Found this from a quick google about using `stdin.write()`, perhaps it could help? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40384109/2403000

Comment: you could try `strout, stderr = p.communicate("position 1 detect on")` and then get results `stdout.read()`